# Replacing multiple word instances with .replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make converting cheat codes into HTML format easier by using user input and JS.

For example, the following code should convert R1, R1, CIRCLE, R2, LEFT, RIGHT, LEFT, RIGHT, LEFT, RIGHT to

```
<div class="ps3 r1"></div>        
<div class="ps3 r1"></div>        
<div class="ps3 circle"></div>        
<div class="ps3 r2"></div>        
<div class="ps3 left"></div>        
<div class="ps3 right"></div>
<div class="ps3 left"></div>        
<div class="ps3 right"></div>
<div class="ps3 left"></div>        
<div class="ps3 right"></div>
```

but returns the input replacing the commas, not the button combinations. Any other methods/help would be much appreciated! The console is empty, no errors appear.

JS

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
    var raw = $('#raw').val();                  
    var st1 = raw.replace(/,/g , "");    
    var st2 = st1.replace(/l1/g , "<div class='ps3 l1'></div>");    
    var st3 = st2.replace(/l2/g , "<div class='ps3 l2'></div>");    
    var st4 = st3.replace(/square/g , "<div class='ps3 square'></div>");    
    var st5 = st4.replace(/circle/g , "<div class='ps3 circle'></div>");    
    var st6 = st5.replace(/triangle/g , "<div class='ps3 triangle'></div>");    
    var st7 = st6.replace(/x/g , "<div class='ps3 cross'></div>");    
    var st8 = st7.replace(/r1/g , "<div class='ps3 r1'></div>");    
    var st9 = st8.replace(/r2/g , "<div class='ps3 r2'></div>");    
    var st10 = st9.replace(/right/g , "<div class='ps3 right'></div>");    
    var st11 = st10.replace(/left/g , "<div class='ps3 left'></div>");    

    $('.result').html(st11);
});
```

HTML

```
 <input id="raw" type="text">
 <button class="submit">Generate</button>
 <div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: You told you are replacing `R1`, and you are replacing `r1`? Consider case-sensitiveness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the regex `(l1|l2|square|circle|triangle|x|r1|r2|right|left)`, it will look for any of those and replace them, the `$1` in the second argument will get replaced with whichever is matched

code first puts the input to lowercase, it then removes the commas, then replaces any of the words with the respective html. And you can chain these as each results in a new string.

```
var raw = "R1, R1, CIRCLE, R2, LEFT, RIGHT, LEFT, RIGHT, LEFT";
var html = raw.toLowerCase().
               replace(/,/g,"").
               replace(/(l1|l2|square|circle|triangle|x|r1|r2|right|left)/ig,"<div class='ps3 $1'></div>");
```

`html` will hold (this is formatted, the actual code would all be inline, not that it makes much difference)

```
<div class='ps3 r1'></div> 
<div class='ps3 r1'></div> 
<div class='ps3 circle'></div>
<div class='ps3 r2'></div>
<div class='ps3 left'></div>
<div class='ps3 right'></div>
<div class='ps3 left'></div>
<div class='ps3 right'></div>
<div class='ps3 left'></div>
```

Comment: This is what I was about to post. The only issue is "x" is replaced with "cross". Hopefully they're willing to make the stylesheet change instead of making it ugly. Also, you're using the `i` modifier even though you used `.toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that regex does case-sensitive matching by default, and your input is all in caps, and your matching strings are lowercase.  Just append `i` to your match options and it will work as expected.

I would also note that that's a lot of unnecessary variables: you don't need to create a new variable for each replacement.  Furthermore, you don't even need to have multiple variables.  You can just chain the `.replace` calls:

```
$('.submit').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var raw = $('#raw').val();                  
    var st = raw.replace(/,/g , "")    
        .replace(/l1/ig , "<div class='ps3 l1'>l1</div>")    
        .replace(/l2/ig , "<div class='ps3 l2'>l2</div>")
        .replace(/square/ig , "<div class='ps3 square'>square</div>")    
        .replace(/circle/ig , "<div class='ps3 circle'>circle</div>")  
        .replace(/triangle/ig , "<div class='ps3 triangle'>triangle</div>")    
        .replace(/x/ig , "<div class='ps3 cross'>cross</div>")    
        .replace(/r1/ig , "<div class='ps3 r1'>r1</div>")    
        .replace(/r2/ig , "<div class='ps3 r2'>r2</div>")    
        .replace(/right/ig , "<div class='ps3 right'>right</div>")
        .replace(/left/ig , "<div class='ps3 left'>left</div>");    

    $('.result').html(st);
});
```

Even this seems like way too much repeated code to me, but it's a start....

Here it is in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/xQ6pF/

Edit: I like Patrick and Yann86's answers: it cuts to the chase of the problem and makes the solution much more DRY.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.submit').click(function() {

  var raw = $('#raw').val().split(",");                  

  for(var i = 0 ; i < raw.length ; i++ ){

    var $div = $("<div class='ps3'></div>"); 
    $div.addClass(raw[i].toLowerCase());
    $('.result').append($div);

  }

});
```